# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to perform an analysis on multiple .csv files. 
I have a folder with 500+ .csv and I would like to extract some information from each of them, creating then a unique .csv with the information I have extracted.
I am thinking of opening a single file, perform the computations (e.g. extract the RMS, the max, the min), store these values in a new DataFrame using the append() method and them move on to the next file.
Unfortunately, as of now, I am stuck with the problem in the title. When it comes to analyse the file in output I have the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
new_df=[]
temp_cols=['Hour','Minute','Second','x_second','RTD_sensor']
### Set your path to the folder containing the .csv files
PATH = 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\python\\NASA\\FEMTOBearingDataSet\\Training_set\\Bearing1_1\\temp\\' # Use your path

### Fetch all files in path
fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

### Filter file name list for files ending with .csv
fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]

### Loop over all files
for file in fileNames:

    ### Read .csv file and append to list
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, sep=',', header=None, names=temp_cols, index_col = None)
    for column in range(0,len(temp_cols)):
        new_df['Mean'].append(df.iloc[:,column].mean())

new_df.head()
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-55-4a40c157922b> in <module>()
         19     df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, sep=',', header=None, names=temp_cols, index_col = None)
         20     for column in range(0,len(temp_cols)):
    ---> 21         new_df['Mean'].append(df.iloc[:,column].mean())
         22 
         23     ### Create line for every file
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: you create `new_df=[]` as a list, not a dataframe, then you use `new_df['Mean']` - the `Mean` is a `str` (string).

Comment: yes, you're right! thank you!